# Test if an execute block succeeded or failed

Tags: chef-infra

I have an `execute` block that runs some tests like so:

```
execute "run tests" do
  command "./phpunit --group all"
  cwd "#{app_dir}"
  returns 0
  action :run
end
```

This works, but I want to report the results as pass/fail. Is there a way to check what the return value was? I could then call another block to report pass (0) or fail(1).

Answer (score 3):

Chef resources doesn't have output values, either the resource action succeeds or it fails and aborts the converge. What you might be looking for is a `not_if`/`only_if` guard clause on the other resource.

Comment: Which is odd, since it must be testing against my `returns` value. Can I do an `only_if` based on the success or failure of the enclosing block (I guessing no)? Otherwise I have to find another way to test if the tests passed or failed...

Comment: Maybe it's odd because Chef is a DSC system and not a test runner? ;-)

Comment: Indeed, use a tool like Test Kitchen or raw InSpec for server testing.

Comment: Yeah, I would really like to avoid using Chef if possible. Thanks!

Comment: How about using [Mixlib::Shellout](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/opscode/mixlib-shellout/Mixlib/ShellOut). if you can sacrifice LWRP for ruby code it is worth for adding more conditional statement. Off course you can use it inside recipe.

Comment: Never use Mixlib::ShellOut directly from Chef code. There are wrappers, but in this case InSpec would probably be better anyway, or maybe Chef Audit Mode.